# Is it possible to lock the complete device from a flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to lock my android device as soon as a particular event happens in an application. The application will keep running in the background and lock the device as soon as the event happens. I tried plugins like [flutter_screen_lock](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screen_lock) but they only provide locking within the particular app while I want the complete device to get locked.

Comment: this sounds like a virus/ransomware, so i'd hope that this sort of thing isn't easily achievable :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer to your question this **is not possible**. If it would be possible both App Distribution Providers (App- and Play Store) would not accept your App because it would be against those Rules.